# Transforming a Complicated Requirement into a SQL Query

Tags: mysql, sql

I am having trouble with the relational algebra and transformation into SQL of this rather complicated query:

I need to select all values from table A joined to table B where there are no matching records in table B, or there are matching records but the set of matching records do not have a field that contains one of 4 of a possible 8 total values.

Database is MySQL 5.0... using an InnoDB engine for the tables.

Comment: Its easy. You need to write a query to table A joined to table B where there are no matching records in table B, or there are matching records but the set of matching records do not have a field that contains one of 4 of a possible 8 total values.

Comment: What do you mean by `the set of matching records do not have a field that contains one of 4 of a possible 8 total values`? Could the possible values be in more than one field, and are there 4 or 8 values to check against?

Comment: Sorry, to clarify the point:  The records from A either need to have no matching records in B (I think that's pretty clear and everyone gets that) OR the records from A can have matching records in B but ONLY matching records that do not have the "state" field with one of the unwanted values (if any of record A's matching records in B have one of the unwanted states, that record in A needs to be thrown away)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if there is any real performance improvement but one other way is:

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    tableA
WHERE
    id NOT IN ( SELECT id FROM tableB WHERE field1 NOT IN ("value1", "value2"));
```

Comment: You only want the Ids from Table B that don't have one of the possible values - you want to exclude this set from A. Then again my interpretation is the same as @llion so I guess we need OP to clarify.

Comment: This is actually the solution I came around to after talking to a few people.  I have the "sub-selects are EVIL" thing drilled into me from when I was just starting to program, but in this case the query performed exceptionally well.

Answer (score 3):

```
Select 
  a.* 
from 
  a 
left join 
  b 
on 
  a.id=b.id 
where 
  b.id is null 
or 
  b.field1 not in ("value1","value2","value3","value4");
```

Comment: This does not work - Your query returns A rows if there exists no matching B rows or if there exists at least one matching B row without the forbidden value. Your query allows A rows with a matching B containing a forbidden value. The OP wants no A row if there exists at least one B row with forbidden value. (at least that is how I interpret the question)

Comment: @dbenham: I think the query matches the OP's description - except that he wants `SELECT *`.

Comment: For me the key phrase is *"the set of matching records do not have..."*. We'll just have to wait for the OP to clarify.

Comment: I may have been reading too selectively on what he wanted to select. I think I see what @dbenham is saying... if there are multiple B records should we return all that do not have the forbidden value or do we return none if any of them do? My solution solves the first. A subselect would be needed to solve the second.

Answer (score 0):

Your requirements are a bit unclear. My 1st interpretation is that you only want the A columns, and never more than 1 instance of a given A row.

```
select * from A where not exists (
  select B.id 
    from B 
   where B.id=A.id 
     and B.field in ('badVal1','badVal2','badVal3','badVal4')
)
```

My 2nd interpretation is you want  all columns from (A outer joined to B), with perhaps more than one instance of an A row if there are multiple B rows, as long as not exists B row with forbidden value.

```
select * from A
  left outer join B on A.id=B.id
 where not exists (
               select C.id
                 from B as C
                where A.id=C.id
                  and C.field in ('badVal1','badVal2','badVal3','badVal4')
           )
```

Both queries could be expressed using NOT IN instead of correlated NOT EXISTS. Its hard to know which would be faster without knowing the data.